# INSERT SELECT loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to transfer data from one table to another. But in the process I need to do something extra I am just wondering is it possible to do something like this in SQL or PL/SQL alone.

```
      source                    target
-------------------       ------------------------
| id | name | qty |       | id | source_id | qty |
-------------------       ------------------------
| 1  | test | 2   |       | 1  | 1         | 1   |
-------------------       ------------------------
| 2  | ago  | 1   |       | 2  | 1         | 1   |    
-------------------       ------------------------
                          | 3  | 2         | 1   |
                          -----------------------
```

Here based on the quantity in source table I will have to insert multiple records. Quantity could be of any number. ID in target table is auto incremented. I tried this

```
INSERT INTO target (SELECT id, qty FROM source);
```

But this does not take care of the qty loop.

Comment: I'd think you'd need PL/SQL to accomplish that, but I also wonder what your primary key will be on the new table.

Comment: PL/SQL is fine as well ID in target table is auto increment. I have updated by question.

Comment: So, if the id is auto generated, how do you plan to make sure the source_id's will be in order? Or is that irrelevant - you really just need to generate source_id and qty, and they can be assigned any (new) id in `target`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain SQL:

```
with
     inputs ( id, qty ) as (
       select 1, 2 from dual union all
       select 2, 1 from dual union all
       select 3, 5 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select row_number() over (order by id) as id, id as source_id, 1 as qty
from   inputs
connect by level <= qty
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;
```

NOTE - if the id is generated automatically, just drop the `row_number().... as id` column; the rest is unchanged.

```
ID  SOURCE_ID  QTY
--  ---------  --
 1          1   1
 2          1   1
 3          2   1
 4          3   1
 5          3   1
 6          3   1
 7          3   1
 8          3   1
```

Comment: Sorry, I overwrote it - will fix. It's at the end of the WITH clause. (I overwrote it when I added the comment about where the solution begins.)

Comment: By the way, if you need to use this in an `INSERT`, you must write it like so: `INSERT INTO ....   SELECT ID, 1 FROM SOURCE CONNECT BY...` You don't need the `WITH` clause at all, because you already have your `SOURCE` table, and you don't need to use column aliases (you have the column names for the `TARGET` table), and you don't need the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...` if the new `id` is auto generated.

Comment: DB server is down I will try when it comes back up. Thank you very much for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TARGET(source_id, qty)
    WITH
    output
    AS
    (
      SELECT id, qty FROM source
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, qty - 1 FROM source WHERE qty > 1
    )    
    SELECT
    id, count(*) as qty 
    FROM output
    group by 
    id, quantity
    ORDER BY
    id
```

Comment: You can't use WITH clause with INSERT like that. Also, it is not clear where you created the new ID column - in fact you are generating just two columns.

Comment: The author has mentioned the ID field is auto increment column in comments and SQL server supports CTEs

Comment: Oh... I missed that.

Comment: The whole WITH clause should be moved right before SELECT - at least in Oracle. Oracle supports CTEs too, just not with that syntax for INSERT statements. And I didn't see the reference to SQL Server; the question is tagged Oracle.

Comment: SQL is fine. You mentioned SQL **Server**, a specific database product (from Microsoft). You realize they are distinct, right? There are three solutions right now, and they all use SQL - and specifically the Oracle version of SQL. In that regard, your current INSERT statement is syntactically incorrect - check the Oracle documentation (or test your own solution) and you will see. I already told you how to fix it to comply with Oracle syntax.

Comment: @mathguy: Thanks. Corrected!

Comment: This only takes care of the situation where qty = 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using SQL. Use CTE to generate amount of rows that matches your maximum `qty` from source table and use non-equi `JOIN` for generating rows. Use `row_number` analytic function to assign each row it's unique id *(if you have it in your target table, check below on my **Edit**)*:

```
with gen_numbers(r) as (
select rownum r
from dual
connect by rownum <= (select max(qty) from src) -- our maximum limit of rows needed
)
select
  row_number() over (order by src.id) as id,
  src.id as source_id, 
  1 as qty
from src
join gen_numbers on src.qty <= gen_numbers.r; -- clone rows qty times
```

Note that you can safely put in constans value `1` in the output of `qty`.

---

Your test data:

```
create table src (id int, name varchar(255), qty int);
insert into src (id, name, qty) 
  select 1, 'test', 2 from dual union all
  select 2, 'ago',  1 from dual
  ;
```

Result:

```
ID  SOURCE_ID   QTY
1   2           1
2   2           1
3   1           1
```

---

***Edit:*** Since your target id column is auto incremented, you don't need the `row_number`. Just specify it like that to perform an `INSERT`:

```
with gen_numbers(r) as (
select rownum r
from dual
connect by rownum <= (select max(qty) from src) -- our maximum limit of rows needed
)
insert into target_table(source_id, qty)
select
  src.id as source_id, 
  1 as qty
from src
join gen_numbers on src.qty <= gen_numbers.r; -- clone rows qty times
order by src.id
```

Notice that I've added an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure proper ordering of inserting values.

Comment: The new id's should be sequential numbers from 1 to 3.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that. Corrected :-)

Comment: Well, in the meantime it was pointed out to me that in a Comment, the OP said the id is generated by the system!

Comment: Realised that as well. Edited my answer appropriately ;-)